# Adding an And/Or statement to document.cookie.indexOf

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can i create an Or statement from what I have now... I want to do a check to see if `urlParams["rs"]` is undefined / null

If cookie **123_rs** is not present and URL query **urlParams["rs"]** is not null/undefined then ...write cookie only if its not present and query string exist

```
if(document.cookie.indexOf("123_rs=") < 0) {
```

Comment: Try `document.cookie.split("123_rs=")`. If you get an array of length `2`, then key exists in cookie. You can even do `retArray[1].split(";")` to get value of cookie

Answer (score 1):

```
if(document.cookie.indexOf("123_rs=") < 0 || !urlParams["rs"])
```

Simply use the or operator?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) operator to combine multiple conditions that must all evaluate to true.

```
if(
    document.cookie.indexOf("123_rs=") < 0 &&
    (typeof urlParams["rs"] != 'undefined') &&
    urlParams["rs"] != ''
) {
    // 123_rs is not found in the cookie string
    // urlParams["rs"] is set and is not an empty string
}
```

---

Sidenote: the cookie check is very simple and is susceptible to false positives. For example if you had a cookie called `abcde123_rs` then your `indexOf()` would still consider it found `123_rs=`. For a more robust solution you can use the [MDN simple cookie library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework):

```
if(
    docCookies.getItem('123_rs') == null &&
    (typeof urlParams["rs"] != 'undefined') &&
    urlParams["rs"] != ''
) {
    // 123_rs is not found
    // urlParams["rs"] is set and is not an empty string
}
```